# Generate synthetic data from a graph (e.g., bipartite)

Tags: graph-theory, synthetic-data

Does anyone know of literature describing methods for generating synthetic data from a graphical structure that has been learned from observations of real data? The graph, depending on the type of data or the questions being asked of it, could be bipartite (as in topic modeling), or directed (as in a link graph-type application). I have spent quite some time researching this, and the closest I've been able to find on this is research on generating synthetic data from statistical distributions that have been learned from training data.

Comment: When you say a "graphical structure that has been learned from observations of real data" do you mean a probabilistic graphical model?

Comment: @Bitwise No, I suppose one situation I'm thinking of is a link graph, such as if I were to create a directed graph from page links on wikipedia.

Comment: so what do you mean by "generating synthetic data"? Do you want to generate random graphs that have similar properties? Can you give a more explicit definition of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Bitwise: No, I want to generate synthetic data that would build a graph that is statistically similar to the original link graph. I'm just curious if anyone has already done this. There's loads of research on synthetic data generation, but none that I can find that uses a graph for the generative process.

Comment: Statistically similar in what sense? Vertex degrees? Number of edges? There are many different properties you could think of. But yes, this is something people do, for example when they want to study the distribution of graphs that have a certain property.

Comment: @Bitwise: All of those. I'm thinking more of a general framework for conducting & evaluating these types of experiments. Can you recommend a reference? I'm particularly interested in evaluations of the synthetic data created from the graph!